# How would I choose 2 random cards from a .txt file then make sure those cards are never used again? (python)

Tags: python, csv

So far I have done this

```
nums = random.sample(range(30), 30)

num1 = nums[0]

with open("cards.txt","r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)  
    for row in reader:
        for field in row:
            if 1 == num1:
                print(row[1])
```

ok so this is very small but I know I need a while loop to but I have created a random list from 0-29 for each individual card.

The card txt each on there own line:

```
Red-1,0
Red-2,1
Red-3,2
Red-4,3
Red-5,4
Red-6,5
Red-7,6
Red-8,7
Red-9,8
Red-10,9
Yellow-1,0 
Yellow-2,1
Yellow-3,2
Yellow-4,3
Yellow-5,4
Yellow-6,5
Yellow-7,6
Yellow-8,7
Yellow-9,8
Yellow-10,9
Black-1,0
Black-2,1
Black-3,2
Black-4,3
Black-5,4
Black-6,5
Black-7,6
Black-8,7
Black-9,8
Black-10,9
```

Then I want to use this number to get the row of the card then print it with smt like this:

> print("Player 1", card)

After that I want to score each player with 1 point to (if both cards are the same colour) the higher numbered card or if not red beats black, yellow beats red and black beats yellow

Then I want to discard or ignore the already used cards and do it again.

If you can help with even one part of this problem I will be thankful.

Edit:

People have said I should check other places and I tell you I HAVE I just need help thanks

https://repl.it/talk/share/edit-if-u-want-I-am-confused/111372

Check if you want: ^

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: There are many resources available on line to show you how to work with a deck of cards in various ways.  We expect yo uto do this research before posting a question here.

Comment: @Prune I have dude any recommendations

Comment: If you *had* done so, you would have a specific question.  ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: first you have to read all cards and `append()` to list `deck`. Later you can use `len(deck)` with `random.randint()` to get random number (smaller then `len(deck)`) and use it with `deck.pop(number)` to get random card from `deck` (and card will not use again). Eventually you can use `random.shuffle(deck)` to create list with cards  in random order and then you can use `for card in deck:` to get cards in random order and card will never used again.

Answer (score 0):

First: I will not try to read from file but I would generate in code

```
colors = ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Black']
#figures = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
figures = range(1, 11)

deck = [ (c, f, f"{c}-{f}") for c in colors for f in figures ]

for card in deck:
    print(card)
```

Result:

```
('Red', 1, 'Red-1')
('Red', 2, 'Red-2')
('Red', 3, 'Red-3')
('Red', 4, 'Red-4')
('Red', 5, 'Red-5')
('Red', 6, 'Red-6')
('Red', 7, 'Red-7')
('Red', 8, 'Red-8')
('Red', 9, 'Red-9')
('Red', 10, 'Red-10')
('Yellow', 1, 'Yellow-1')
('Yellow', 2, 'Yellow-2')
('Yellow', 3, 'Yellow-3')
('Yellow', 4, 'Yellow-4')
('Yellow', 5, 'Yellow-5')
('Yellow', 6, 'Yellow-6')
('Yellow', 7, 'Yellow-7')
('Yellow', 8, 'Yellow-8')
('Yellow', 9, 'Yellow-9')
('Yellow', 10, 'Yellow-10')
('Black', 1, 'Black-1')
('Black', 2, 'Black-2')
('Black', 3, 'Black-3')
('Black', 4, 'Black-4')
('Black', 5, 'Black-5')
('Black', 6, 'Black-6')
('Black', 7, 'Black-7')
('Black', 8, 'Black-8')
('Black', 9, 'Black-9')
('Black', 10, 'Black-10')

len(deck): 30
```

When you will have all cards in list `deck` then you can use `random.shuffle` to create deck with cards in random order (like in real game). Because `shuffle` doesn't create new list but it changes order in original list (it changes `"in-place"`) so I would duplicate it to keep original `deck`

```
random_deck = deck.copy()
random.shuffle(random_deck)  # change order "in-place"
```

And now I can use `for`-loop to get random cards and they will never repeate

```
for card in random_deck:
    print(card)
```

Result:

```
('Black', 2, 'Black-2')
('Yellow', 9, 'Yellow-9')
('Red', 6, 'Red-6')
('Black', 9, 'Black-9')
('Black', 6, 'Black-6')
('Yellow', 4, 'Yellow-4')
('Black', 1, 'Black-1')
('Red', 3, 'Red-3')
('Yellow', 6, 'Yellow-6')
('Black', 5, 'Black-5')
('Red', 1, 'Red-1')
('Yellow', 8, 'Yellow-8')
('Black', 10, 'Black-10')
('Red', 9, 'Red-9')
('Yellow', 3, 'Yellow-3')
('Yellow', 5, 'Yellow-5')
('Black', 3, 'Black-3')
('Red', 4, 'Red-4')
('Red', 5, 'Red-5')
('Yellow', 1, 'Yellow-1')
('Black', 7, 'Black-7')
('Red', 2, 'Red-2')
('Yellow', 10, 'Yellow-10')
('Red', 7, 'Red-7')
('Red', 10, 'Red-10')
('Yellow', 2, 'Yellow-2')
('Yellow', 7, 'Yellow-7')
('Black', 4, 'Black-4')
('Red', 8, 'Red-8')
('Black', 8, 'Black-8')
```

Now I could use it to get cards for players like this

```
current_player = 1

for card in random_deck:
    if current_player == 1:
         print('Player 1:',  card)
         current_player = 2
    else:
         print('Player 2:', card)
         current_player = 1
```

but it is not so useful because in every loop I have only one new card only for only one player.

It will be simpler to split `deck` into 2 parts and gets two carts.

Because `deck` has 30 cards so I could split in middle - on first 15 cards and second 15 cards

```
first_part  = random_deck[:15]
second_part = random_deck[15:]
```

or I can split on odd and even card in deck

```
even = random_deck[0::2]
odd  = random_deck[1::2]
```

or I could try to use other method - but because deck was shuffled at start so now I don't have to try to get cards in random order.

Now I can use `zip()` to get two cards - one from first part and one from second part and I will have two different random cards and they will never repeate

```
even = random_deck[0::2]
odd  = random_deck[1::2]

for card1, card2 in zip(even, odd):
    print('Player 1 --> | {:10} | {:10} | <-- Player2'.format(card1[2], card2[2]) )
```

Result:

```
Player 1 --> | Yellow-6   | Red-1      | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Red-8      | Black-1    | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Red-9      | Black-5    | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Red-2      | Yellow-8   | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Black-6    | Black-7    | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Red-5      | Black-2    | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Yellow-4   | Yellow-9   | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Yellow-5   | Yellow-7   | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Black-3    | Black-8    | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Red-7      | Black-10   | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Red-3      | Red-10     | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Yellow-10  | Black-9    | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Red-4      | Black-4    | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Yellow-1   | Yellow-3   | <-- Player2
Player 1 --> | Yellow-2   | Red-6      | <-- Player2
```

And now it is easy to compare two cards. I compare only values so you will have to do rest.

```
even = random_deck[0::2]
odd  = random_deck[1::2]

for card1, card2 in zip(even, odd):
    diff = card1[1] - card2[1]

    if diff < 0:
        result = 'Player 2'
    elif diff > 0:
        result = 'Player 1'
    else:
        result = 'draw'

    print('Player 1 --> | {:10} | {:10} | <-- Player2 | {}'.format(card1[2], card2[2], result) )
```

`for`-loop will finish when there will be no more unused cards.